# How to Use Custom NavigationPage with MVVMCross library in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I am trying to provide my own `XAML` NavigationPage instead of the one generated by "WrapInNavigationPage" property from my `MvxMasterDetailPresentation` Attribute on `MvxContentPage`.

I have been looking through the `MvvmCross` docs and samples. Someone pointed me to the Xamarin Forms View Presenters. However, I saw no practical example or documentation.

I have tried subclassing the `MvxFormsPagePresenter` and override the "`CreateNavigationPage`" method, however that didn't have any effect. See my code below:

```
using MomentsMobile.Pages.Common;
using MvvmCross.Forms.Presenters;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MomentsMobile.Core.Presenters
{
    public class MvxFormsCustomViewPresenter: MvxFormsPagePresenter
    {
       public MvxFormsCustomViewPresenter(IMvxFormsViewPresenter presenter):base(presenter)
       {
       }

       protected override NavigationPage CreateNavigationPage(Page pageRoot = null)
       {
          return new CustomNavigationPage(pageRoot);
          // return base.CreateNavigationPage(pageRoot);
       }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why my custom NavigationPage is not used to wrap the content page of my MasterDetail?